# How to enable fill-handle, copy-paste a whole dataset ( drag and drop ), multi select cells in vue-excel-editor for vue 2?

Tags: excel, vuejs2

I'm currently working on a project using Vue 2 and the vue-excel-editor component. I'm seeking guidance on enabling the fill-handle, copy-paste a whole dataset ( drag and drop ) & multi select feature within the vue-excel-editor.

I've explored the documentation and attempted to implement the fill-handle, but I haven't been successful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.